# How to increment decimal values in cell in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA coding and need some help in writing a loop to increment the cells and increment the cell contents by a decimal value.

searched internet and found a do while loop code which is incrementing only numbers, not able to increment decimal values

```
Sub Doeg()
    Dim counter As Double
    counter = 1

    Do While counter < 10
        Cells(counter, "A"). Value = counter
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

the above code is incrementing the cells and the value of each cell by `1`.
I want to start with `1.2` and increment the value of each cell by `0.1` for ten values

Comment: Why then assign it the value 1 and increment it by 1?

Comment: You begin with a value of 1 and then increment by the integer 1. What did you *think* would happen? How do you think you should resolve it for your start value of 1.2 and increment of 0.1??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so. `For-Next` seems a better option in this case.

```
Sub Doeg()

Dim counter As Long

For counter = 1 To 10
    Cells(counter, "A").Value = (counter - 1) * 0.1 + 1.2
Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops not needed.

```
Sub Doeg()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        .Formula = "=(ROW()-1)*.01+1.2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want a loop I would get in the practice of looping Variant Arrays instead of Ranges:

```
Sub Doeg()
    Dim otArr(1 to 10, 1 to 1) as Variant

    Dim i as Long
    For i = LBound(otArr,1) to UBound(otArr,1)
        otArr(i,1) = (i - 1) * 0.1 + 1.2
    Next i

   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(otArr,1),UBound(otArr,2)).Value = otArr
End Sub
```

Though in this specific instance the time to complete will not be noticeably different but if you had 1000 or even 100,000 then the time becomes noticeable.

---

But to what SJR was suggesting in the comment above.

Change `counter = 1` to `counter = 1.2`

Change `Do While counter < 10` to `Do While counter < 10 * 0.1 + 1.2`

And Change `counter = counter + 1` to `counter = counter + 0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Sub Doeg()
Dim counter As Double
counter = 1.1
Do While counter < 10
Cells(counter, "A").Value = counter
counter = counter + 1.1
counter = counter - 0.1
Loop
End Sub
```